# Transform coordinates from Long Island Zone to Lat. Long format with R

Tags: r, gis, rgdal

I have the following data set with coordinates in the State Plane Coordinate System from 1983. All coordinates are located in the Long Island Zone (3104).

```
dput(example)
structure(c(1008031L, 1000852L, 1001869L, 1005306L, 986887L, 
998031L, 1018703L, 1014319L, 1016186L, 1006977L, 1006891L, 1000883L, 
1001403L, 999812L, 1010077L, 1015918L, 984241L, 1013735L, 986848L, 
998243L, 1007312L, 1005663L, 992415L, 999771L, 1006787L, 987215L, 
990271L, 1015773L, 999342L, 1007245L, 1007098L, 996980L, 1006886L, 
999643L, 1008769L, 1016489L, 1004212L, 986848L, 1001512L, 1002584L, 
1001753L, 1004625L, 990725L, 1013435L, 1010795L, 1007509L, 1009419L, 
NA, 1009731L, 999007L, 999007L, 1000195L, 985863L, 990064L, 1008192L, 
1008306L, NA, 1003280L, 1006541L, 1001264L, 1003844L, 1008345L, 
987951L, 999104L, 1009013L, 998201L, 984182L, 1004940L, 1004513L, 
999659L, 1018204L, 1005918L, 1008158L, 999629L, 982208L, 1008008L, 
983985L, 1003591L, 992033L, 1012144L, 1008285L, 1004196L, 999937L, 
1007579L, 1001610L, 1013897L, 985504L, 1003588L, 1000088L, 1002230L, 
999304L, 1001393L, 997666L, 999148L, 997501L, 1004670L, 994699L, 
1005950L, 994821L, 998160L, 233036L, 228179L, 190702L, 186668L, 
173599L, 234924L, 241414L, 182198L, 178657L, 178140L, 242280L, 
236356L, 235184L, 238138L, 181374L, 245648L, 149582L, 211309L, 
212883L, 176387L, 243183L, 237170L, 149315L, 188471L, 242047L, 
215403L, 203844L, 240835L, 233575L, 234932L, 166665L, 174885L, 
193881L, 228852L, 244547L, 247336L, 178750L, 212883L, 232231L, 
248715L, 182080L, 242885L, 204176L, 251857L, 183147L, 245160L, 
235573L, NA, 243613L, 229814L, 229814L, 229856L, 212233L, 225331L, 
245037L, 245316L, NA, 229886L, 243541L, 232832L, 250988L, 235949L, 
220453L, 192913L, 242619L, 173610L, 150037L, 169914L, 180635L, 
229932L, 239783L, 190990L, 244973L, 243379L, 170319L, 246638L, 
205857L, 242274L, 215119L, 236944L, 245256L, 183865L, 238365L, 
183413L, 241367L, 238753L, 216029L, 249617L, 230093L, 176647L, 
227192L, 200533L, 177016L, 187285L, 170971L, 233870L, 176744L, 
179753L, 177866L, 227234L), .Dim = c(100L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("xcoord", "ycoord")))
```

I need to have the coordinates in lat./long. format or wgs84.

Can someone tell me how I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This looks helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-convert-state-plane-coordinates-to-latitude-longitude

Comment: and this http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proj4/proj4.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have seen both but couldn't understand them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative to `rgdal` is `proj4` package.  It has `transform` function.  I guessed the projection being used was http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32118/

```
library(proj4)
dat <- structure(c(1008031L, 1000852L, 1001869L, 1005306L, 986887L, 
998031L, 1018703L, 1014319L, 1016186L, 1006977L, 1006891L, 1000883L, 
1001403L, 999812L, 1010077L, 1015918L, 984241L, 1013735L, 986848L, 
998243L, 1007312L, 1005663L, 992415L, 999771L, 1006787L, 987215L, 
990271L, 1015773L, 999342L, 1007245L, 1007098L, 996980L, 1006886L, 
999643L, 1008769L, 1016489L, 1004212L, 986848L, 1001512L, 1002584L, 
1001753L, 1004625L, 990725L, 1013435L, 1010795L, 1007509L, 1009419L, 
NA, 1009731L, 999007L, 999007L, 1000195L, 985863L, 990064L, 1008192L, 
1008306L, NA, 1003280L, 1006541L, 1001264L, 1003844L, 1008345L, 
987951L, 999104L, 1009013L, 998201L, 984182L, 1004940L, 1004513L, 
999659L, 1018204L, 1005918L, 1008158L, 999629L, 982208L, 1008008L, 
983985L, 1003591L, 992033L, 1012144L, 1008285L, 1004196L, 999937L, 
1007579L, 1001610L, 1013897L, 985504L, 1003588L, 1000088L, 1002230L, 
999304L, 1001393L, 997666L, 999148L, 997501L, 1004670L, 994699L, 
1005950L, 994821L, 998160L, 233036L, 228179L, 190702L, 186668L, 
173599L, 234924L, 241414L, 182198L, 178657L, 178140L, 242280L, 
236356L, 235184L, 238138L, 181374L, 245648L, 149582L, 211309L, 
212883L, 176387L, 243183L, 237170L, 149315L, 188471L, 242047L, 
215403L, 203844L, 240835L, 233575L, 234932L, 166665L, 174885L, 
193881L, 228852L, 244547L, 247336L, 178750L, 212883L, 232231L, 
248715L, 182080L, 242885L, 204176L, 251857L, 183147L, 245160L, 
235573L, NA, 243613L, 229814L, 229814L, 229856L, 212233L, 225331L, 
245037L, 245316L, NA, 229886L, 243541L, 232832L, 250988L, 235949L, 
220453L, 192913L, 242619L, 173610L, 150037L, 169914L, 180635L, 
229932L, 239783L, 190990L, 244973L, 243379L, 170319L, 246638L, 
205857L, 242274L, 215119L, 236944L, 245256L, 183865L, 238365L, 
183413L, 241367L, 238753L, 216029L, 249617L, 230093L, 176647L, 
227192L, 200533L, 177016L, 187285L, 170971L, 233870L, 176744L, 
179753L, 177866L, 227234L), .Dim = c(100L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("xcoord", "ycoord")))

lonlat <- project(dat, 
    '+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs ', 
    inverse=T)
```

Comment: Nice. In the end, I think both solutions are using the PROJ4 library to do the projection.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guessed the same epsg projection by googling it. But how do you know which one it is? And how do you know what to write between the '' in the project command? So that I don't have to ask the next time if there is a different projection... ;-)

Comment: @Dominik, those q better be posted to gis.stackexchange.com.  Ultimately only folks who did the projection know for sure and often time they don't know exactly...  one method which often I use is to find several of object which I can identify on google earth and see how the lon/lat of my inverse projection shows up.  and determine magnitude of error is acceptable for my application.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `rgdal` and `sp`.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
# I made a guess at the PROJ4 string that your data was in. This is using SRID: 2831
long.island.proj4<-CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
# Remove the missing values in your data, and convert to SpatialPoints
sp.points<-SpatialPoints(example[complete.cases(example),],proj4string=long.island.proj4)
# Project to lat/long
spTransform(sp.points,CRS('+proj=longlat'))
```

Comment: How did you know that this is SRID: 2831? And where can I find informations, who the CRS command needs to look like? So that I don't have to ask the next time if there is a different projection... ;-)

Comment: @Dominik Use [the link provided in the other answer](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/). Search for 'Long Island', then click the PROJ4 string.